# Node.js / JS - direct csv data manipulation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I know it can be done in other languages like Powershell, I did a lot of searching but couldn't find any how it can be done in node.js or javascript.

For example let's say I have:

```
carModel,price,color
"Audi",10000,"blue"
"BMW",15000,"red"
"Mercedes",20000,"yellow"
"Porsche",30000,"green"
```

and I want to append to line 3 something like:

```
carModel,price,color,errorcode,errormsg
"Audi",10000,"blue"
"BMW",15000,"red","05","wrong price"
"Mercedes",20000,"yellow"
"Porsche",30000,"green"
```

My question isn't really about how to solve the above, but:

Is there any way to manipulate a csv file in js *directly* without converting it to json objects and converting it back to csv?

Comment: *"without converting it to json objects"* You wouldn't convert it to *JSON* at all. You might well convert it to objects (specifically, arrays), but not JSON. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to manipulate a csv file in js *directly*...

Sure, you could read it all into memory as one big string, then splice content into the string. It probably wouldn't be a great idea, though, as compared to at least reading it in as an array of strings or an array of arrays.

Also note that reading a CSV can be more work than it seems thanks to line breaks within quoted fields, etc., so you're probably best off using one of the CSV parser npm modules...

Comment: Ok, so it would be to convert the lines to object lines (or array) ...and to add to specific index the two new fields?

Comment: just get an `npm` package for it.